# Exports undefined when trying to bundle a typescript library with webpack

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I have a library that I'm developing in typescript. I have the solution to build it via tsc to use it as an npm package, but tsc traslates each files individually. I would like to use webpack to create a bundle everything in a single, minified file but it does not work. I made some tests (create a simple package in JS using module.exports/require and it worked, a JS package that failed using the es6 syntax export/import) so I think that i comes from the import/export syntax of typescript... But I expected the loader (I tried ts-loader et awesome-ts-loader) to translate it but in each case when I try to import a bundled package it always returns "undefined".

this is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

(for module and target I tried to change to commonjs for module and older targs, but it doesn't change anything....)

Here is the webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: '',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        libraryExport: 'default'
    }
};
```

and a very simpe src/index.ts

```
export function foo() {
    console.log('this is foo');
}
```

but impossible to import the foo function...
I made a test file, in another project.
I used "npm link" in the library project to register the package in the global modules, and "npm link @kalika-libraries/mixins" in the test project to add it ot the node_modules.
Here is the simple test I made :

```
import * as foo from '@kalika-libraries/mixins';

console.log('foo', foo);
```

But it always logs "undefined"...

I searched for hours, trying different tsconfigs or webpack configs but it always the same... The only case the import worked was when using tsc... But looking at some libraries (like angular) I know that bundled libraries is possible ! I just don't know how to do it (maybe I'm not using the right tools...).

Oh and here is the package.json of the library, just in case:

```
{
    "name": "@kalika-libraries/mixins",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Libraries to apply mixins on classes",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npx webpack"
    },
    "author": "Kalika",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/yeoman-generator": "^3.0.1",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.21.0",
        "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
        "tslint-consistent-codestyle": "^1.15.1",
        "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
        "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3",
        "vrsource-tslint-rules": "^6.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

And I used "npx webpack" commmand in the library folder to build it.

So if you have any idea (hoping you'll not propose solutions I already tried) I'd be glad to test it !

thanks.

Comment: Sorry my answer was wrong and I've deleted it.  My only guess is that there's an issue with your target of es6 in tsconfig.json.  Although you'd think there would be an error instead of an export of undefined.

Answer (score 5):

I faced with the same problem. And this solved it for me:

In webpack.config.js:

```
output: {
  ...
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  library: 'MyPackageName',
  ...
}
```

in tsconfig.json:

```
compilerOptons: {
  ...
  "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's far from obvious for a first time ts/js npm library developer using webpack that during build it uses a series of optimizations by default that remove a lot of code that it determines unused.

When creating a library, wepack needs to be told explicitly so it does not remove your exports:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/